# Acumatica Report Designer Format Decimal Points

Tags: report, acumatica

Can anyone tell me what is the Format required to get decimal points to be displayed dynamically so that the field displays "5" if I enter "5.0" and "5.5" if I enter "5.5" automatically.

I have tried using #0.# as the format, but this is leaving the "." as in "5." if I enter "5.0". I have left the field as "#0.0" but would really like to know if there was a way of dynamically change the decimal places this way

Comment: Also tried #0# with no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer was ##.# :)

Answer (score 1):

You can pull in the correct decimals for quantity and cost as specified on the Branch record by using a database field and an expression.

```
=Report.IntToUI('AMMTran.UnitCost',CDec([AMMTran.UnitCost]))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following formula too: 
=Format('{0:0.#}', 5.5)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [answer]. You should provide some information why your code solves the problem.